# The set of integers is or The set of integers are

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

May I know Which one is grammatical?

> A set of integers is returned by the function.
>
> A set of integers are returned by the function.

Answer (score 2):

> **A set** of integers **is** returned by the function - is correct.

The *is* refers to a *set* here. Just like...

> **A crowd** of 100 pupils **was** coming toward the gate.